# AngularJS issue after upgrading to a newer version

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/Clr2T9V8J0z3oxW2HXur?p=preview

The problem I face is that whenever I change the field type from "text" to "radio buttons", I get an error (Line 45 in the script.js in the above plukr page)

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
```

I checked the code but can't seem to be able to spot the problem. I know it's happening because one of the two variables pass

Here is the original source which functions properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/ProLoser/bp3Qu/light/

Notice that "Add Option" link appears when you select "radio button". I can't seem to be able to get to work in the above plunkr.

Can anyone help me fix this issue on line 45?

```
        if (angular.Array.indexOf(['checkboxes','select','radio'], type) === -1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
if (Array.prototype.indexOf(['checkboxes','select','radio'], type) === -1)
```

or just

```
if (['checkboxes','select','radio'].indexOf(type) === -1)
```